# VIM Airline status line does not show caps lock

Tags: vim, capslock, vim-airline

I would like to see if the caps-lock is `ON` or `OFF` in my vim-airline status bar for reasons mentioned [here](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1190). I installed [vim-capslock](https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock) in my bundle and set the variable as `let g:airline#extensions#capslock#enabled = 1`. However, I don't see any difference after opening the VIM. I don't see a `caps-lock` status in the status line. My airline configuration is as below in `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:airline_theme='wombat'

" Enable the list of buffers
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

" Show just the filename
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':t'

" Show capslock status in the statusline
let g:airline#extensions#capslock#enabled = 1
```

I was expecting `CAPS` in the status line if the caps-lock was ON. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how [vim-capslock](https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock) works. It implements a *software* caps-lock in Vim, which affects text you type, but does not affect command keys. And it exports that status so Airline can display it. But it has nothing to do with the hardware caps lock key on your keyboard. I'm not aware of a way to detect the capslock on a keyboard reliably.

Comment: oh okay ! thanks a lot for the clarification. maybe I mis-understood it completely. would it mean that there is no solution?

Comment: Maybe by modifying the caps lock keybinding at the OS level and then assigning the new bind to enable vim-capslock? Never tried something like this though.

Comment: @Vitor sure, but one big drawback: caps lock stops working in all the other apps.

Comment: Apps other than vim? Why do you need then!? :P You could use FocusGained/Lost auto commands (if using gvim) to enable/disable the custom bindings.